How to Reflect Updated Account Data in Subsequent Salesforce Lightning Flow Screens?
I'm working on a Salesforce Lightning Web Component (LWC) designed to be embedded in a Screen Flow. This component allows users to modify an Account record's fields and then updates the record using an Apex controller method updateAccount().The component is also supposed to pass the updated Account record to the next screen in the flow. However, I'm facing an issue where the next screen in the flow still shows the old Account values, not reflecting the updates made in the LWC.
Although the update operation completes successfully (confirmed by console logs showing the updated Account record post-update),the subsequent screen within the flow does not reflect these updates.
Key points:

The LWC is designed to receive an Account record from the parent flow, allow field modifications, and then update the Account via updateAccount() in the controller.

The validate method invokes handleSaveEvent() for the update. Upon a successful update, saveSuccess is set to true, and a FlowAttributeChangeEvent is dispatched to signal the update to the flow.

Both input and output configurations for the Account property are set in the component's metadata, aiming for data flow continuity between the component and the flow screens.

Despite the apparent success of the update operation (as verified through saveSuccess), the subsequent flow screen does not show the updated Account data.


I suspect the issue might be tied to how the updated data is communicated and rendered in the subsequent flow screen, especially considering the sequence involving validation and event dispatching.
Relevant Code Snippets:
JavaScript for Updating Account and Validation Handling:
@api account;
@api isUpdateNeeded = false;
saveSuccess = true;

@api
validate() {
    this.handleSaveEvent();
    if (this.saveSuccess) {
        // Logic to proceed to the next screen, assuming validation passes
        return { isValid: true };
    } else {
        // Logic to handle validation failure
        return {
            isValid: false,
            errorMessage: 'Failed to update Account data.'
        };
    }
}

@api
async handleSaveEvent() {
    this.checkForChange(); // Determines if update based on field changes is needed

    if (this.isUpdateNeeded) {
        this.updatePayload.Id = this.account.Id;
        try {
            await updateAccount({ account: this.updatePayload });
            let help = {...this.account};
            help = Object.assign(help,this.updatePayload);
            this.account = help;

console.log('Updated Account:', JSON.stringify(this.account)); // Confirms the Account update in console
            // Logic to handle successful Account update
            this.saveSuccess = true;
            notifyRecordUpdateAvailable([{ recordId: this.account.Id }]);
            // Dispatching FlowAttributeChangeEvent to signal data update
            this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('account', this.account));
        } catch (error) {
            // Error handling logic
            this.saveSuccess = false;
        }
    }
}


Component Metadata for Flow Configuration:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>60.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="account" type="@salesforce/schema/Account" label="Account" description="The Account record for modification" required="true"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>


Though the update process appears to function correctly, and I use a combination of validation logic and event dispatching to signal updates, the next screen in the flow does not display the updated Account values. How can I ensure the flow accurately reflects the updated Account data after validation and progression to the next screen?

Right now, you are updating account field values by calling apex method from LWC that is asynchronous, so, it can take time, instead of that, consider updating the LWC properties data from flow itself.
